# MVC controller and repository model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I keep getting an error saying that:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'HomebaseSystemNew.Controllers.ProductRepository', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HomebaseSystemNew.Models.Product'

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"           Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomebaseSystemNew.Models.Product>" %>
```

My Repository:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using HomebaseSystemNew.Models;

  namespace HomebaseSystemNew.Controllers
  {
     public class ProductRepository
   {

  public Product GetProductID(int Pid)
    {
        DatabaseLinkedDataContext db = new DatabaseLinkedDataContext();

        return db.Products.FirstOrDefault(ans => ans.Pid == Pid);
    }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
using System.Linq;

using System.Web.Mvc;

using HomebaseSystemNew.Models;


namespace HomebaseSystemNew.Controllers
  {

    public class ProductsController : Controller
 {

       public ActionResult EditProduct(int id)  
       {
             ProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();

             repo.GetProductID(id);

             return View(repo); 
        } 
  }
```

Comment: You really ought to start accepting some answers before posting more...

Answer (score 6):

You are returning the repository in the View not the Product. Change it to this:

```
var product = repo.GetProductID(id);

return View(product );
```

Comment: Or even shorter `return View(repo.GetProductID(id));`

Comment: @James or even shorter `return View(new ProductRepository().GetProductID(id));` ;-)

Comment: @James, or even shorter... `return View(new ProductRepository().GetProductID(id));`

...maybe we should make the repository static to save another 3 letters? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Easy one, just pass in the right type of Model/Class. If you definitely want to pass a ProductRepository Model then change the first line of your View page to be...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"           Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomebaseSystemNew.Controllers.ProductRepository>" %>
```

Alternatively, if you want to pass the Product, then you need to return that in your controller action. (Which on further reading is more likely the one you are trying to do)

Notice the "Inherits" property is being set with the model type that you want to pass.

Also note that you do not typically want to put repositories in your controller folder - best to keep that for just controller classes ;)

Comment: Based on the code in his Action, I think his intent was to pass a product to the View -- not his entire repository.

Comment: @JustinRusbatch: Yep, I made that comment in my post. Either way I think I explain why the error occurs, which is always a helpful addition to just correcting the code for them ;)